# use linqtoexcel in windows services

Tags: c#

I am using LinqtoExcel in my windows Service as shown below, but my issue that throw windows services it is not working and stuck in this method while using it in a consul it is working fine. Please any help??

```
public string[] OpenExcelFileLinq(string exldir, int phone)
        {
            string sheetName = "Autoline";
            var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(exldir);
            var artistAlbums = from p in excelFile.Worksheet(sheetName)
                where p["Phone"] == phone.ToString()
                select p;

            foreach (var a in artistAlbums)
            {
                string cm = a[1];
                string cn = a[2];

                if (a.Any())
                {
                    string[] cust = {cm, cn};
                    return cust;
                }
            }
            string[] notvalid = {"Not Valid", "Not Valid"};
            return notvalid;
```

Comment: please define "not working". you get an exception, or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after a lot of changes and debugging in my code I found that the linqtoexcel can read an excel file with extension .xlsx through console application but it cannot do that through windows service, so I had to extract the excel from other program in .xls extension and managed to solve the issue.

thanks.